# Upvote Downvote message bug

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web

[image]

This screenshot on my mobile shows the upvote and downvote as very big text, even though I didn't add such settings to my phone.

I did a bit of checking and found out that this happens when I do this:

1. Go to desktop view.
2. Click back button
3. Click *show more comments*
4. Surprise, a strange bug

I confirmed that this happens on metaSE and chemSE, will do more testing a while later.

I am unsure if this is a bug or cache error or whatever, but I think I'll post it just in case.

Comment: Probably you are now mixing the mobile theme with dynamically loaded content for desktop.

Comment: What's your browser? No repro on Chrome 59 for Android.

Comment: @iBug I'm using Chrome latest version. I just checked now, and it still works (the bug).

Comment: @Patrick, so is that considered a bug?